# iPhone - Core data crash on some devices

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have an iPhone application which works fine one some devices and causes crash other times when constructing the persistentStoreCoordinator the following the code which causes the application to crash

```
__persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
```

**NOTE : The previous line of code causes the application to crash on some siutations, not on all devices.**

the managedObjectModel implementation is as follows:

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (__managedObjectModel != nil)
    {
        return __managedObjectModel;
    }

    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"iSpot" withExtension:@"momd"];
    __managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];    
    return __managedObjectModel;
}
```

Comment: what does the crash log look like?

Comment: I don't know if this is your problem, but if you change your Core Data structure, then attempt to *re-install* on a device it will crash. Simply manually delete the application from the device before building/installing/running. This gave me a puzzling 30 minutes or so figuring out why it would work on some devices but not others.